# How to update a same field in all objects of a same type in normalised cache?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm using Apollo Client 3 in a react project.
I have a data structure like this:

```
ROOT_QUERY 
  getCollection {
     __typename: 'Collection',
     _id: '123'
     tagColorMap: [
       {__typename: 'Tag',
        name: 'tag1',
        color: "#673ab7",
        count: 3},
       {__typename: 'Tag',
        name: 'tag2',
        color: '#f44336',
        count: 1},
       ...
     ]
     entries: [
       {
         __typename: 'Entry',
         _id: 'asd'
         tags: [tag1, tag2, tag3]
       },
       {
         __typename: 'Entry',
         _id: 'qwe'
         tags: [tag2, tag3]
       },
       ...
     }
  }
```

the data are normalised in the cache.

```
ROOT_QUERY 
  getCollection{
    "__ref": "Collection:123"
  }
Collection:123{
  _id: '123'
  tagColorMap: [
    {__typename: "Tag",
     name: "tag1",
     color: "#673ab7",
     count: 3},
    {__typename: "Tag",
     name: "tag2",
     color: "#f44336",
     count: 1},
    ...
  ]
  entries: [
    {
      __ref: "Entry:asd"
    },
    {
      __ref: "Entry:qwe"
    },
     ...
  ]
Entry:asd {
  _id: 'asd'
  tags: ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']
},
Entry:qwe {
  _id: 'qwe'
  tags: ['tag2', 'tag3']
},
```

I performed a mutation, which renames one of the tag, say 'tag1' -> 'tag11', which returns the new tagColorMap;
now I want to change all 'tag1' into 'tag11' in the cache.
I have gone through the official doc and googled it for a while, but still can't find a way to do this.
refetching won't work because the time between the mutation is done and the refetch is done, all the entries that still have tag 'tag1' don't have a corresponding colour in the colour map, it will fallback to default colour, then back to the original colour after the refetch is done.

another way might be that to let the server return the entire collection after the mutation, which is quite a lot of data

so that's why I would like to rename all 'tag1' into 'tag11' in all 'entry" objects directly in cache, but I couldn't find a way to do this... Could anyone help me with this?

thank you very much in advance!

Comment: ... but you see that tags are not normalized? read docs about custom identifiers (other than `id` or `_id`)

Comment: thanks @xadm! the tags field in the entries are currently just an array of strings. maybe it's a good idea to give an (immutable) id to each tag, and in entries use this fixed id in the array instead. but I was kinda of hoping there's some way I can just interate through the array and replace 'tag10 to 'tag11'

Comment: you can, use `readQuery`/`writeQuery`

Comment: @xadm I had problem with it, I think mainly because in the real project the client gets the "entry" type from multiple differently queries, and  I want to update all of them. and readQuery I somehow can't managed to make a query that returns an array of all "entry" type objects in cache, regardless how they are queried from the server in the first place

Comment: you can use some `collectEntries @client` to build an array of entry ids

Comment: or more general (w/o modifying queries) ... use merge type policy